# BASH: bz2 to gzip conversion with find

Tags: bash, gzip, compression

I would like to convert a muliply `bzip2` files to `gzip` format. I achived this with `foor loop` but I would like to do the same with `find`:

BASH for loop:

```
for i in $(ls -1 *.bz2); do echo "Converting: $i to ${i%.bz2}.gz"; { bunzip2 -c $i | gzip > ${i%.bz2}.gz; }; done
```

I tried something like that but it doesn't work:

```
find . -name "*.bz2" -type f -exec bunzip2 -c {} | gzip > ${1%.bz2}.gz \;
```

Comment: Don't try to get too creative. Just put the conversion into a shell script that only expects the source file name and call it from the `find -exec` routine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so simple. Find can only call a binary with an "exec" argument, but you now try to call a bunzip|gzip pipe. It is not a simple binary, it is a chain of binaries, and to start a such thing you need something, which can handle pipes.

The best thing for this were a shell. You have to call a shell to call this pipe:

```
find . -name "*.bz2" -type f -exec bash -e 'bunzip2 -c {} | gzip > ${1%.bz2}.gz'
```

(I didn't tested it, probable some syntax problem can occur, see this as a template.)